# how to execute code found in a string in php

Tags: php, parsing, string-parsing

heyy,
I want to run the code found in the string below

```
$str=" $row["AccountID"].$row["CurrencyID"] ";
```

like this:

```
while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo $str;
}
```

but the output is shown like this:

```
 $row["AccountID"].$row["CurrencyID"]
```

That's not what i need ,
how can i make it run the code inside the string and allowing it to read the "$row" word as a variable not as a string?

Comment: Don't use quotes.

Comment: Is $str hard coded like this, or is it pulled from another source and $str here is just an example?

Comment: Execute it our output it?

Comment: @Devon it is pulled from another source yes as an example

Comment: @user3783243 it is already outputting the original value shown in the string
i want it to consider the $row as a variable to run it and get the actual value

Comment: Can you 'source' the string inside the loop?  Not sure I'm wrapping my head around this too well.  By assigning it beforehand you're not gonna get values, for certain.  Of course, the Evil Way no one has suggested yet ;-) ;-)  I dunno if that would work.

Comment: `eval("echo $str;");`

Comment: @AbraCadaver It worked!! Thanks alot

Comment: @OsamaAlZahabi, be very careful with eval.  I could inject any command I want into your application if I have any control over the input.

Comment: @Devon ohh thanks for the info but im not taking any input from the user so no worries

Comment: `eval()` is a bad idea. I have no idea why it hasn't been deprecated yet

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi, there are use cases for eval, in testing or mathematical expressions, but the large majority of uses of eval are security holes, so it's more on the developer than the language.

Answer (score 1):

Programming languages, like PHP, will not evaluate strings, for good reason.  You'd have huge security holes in your application if PHP tried to evaluate everything it found in strings.

The reason why `$str = "$row";` works is because PHP is evaluating `"$row"` before the string is even assigned.  The variable `$row` doesn't live in `$str`, the value does.

A common use case is storing a template syntax and replacing the placeholders in your view.  Possible placeholders are `%AccountID%` or `{{AccountID}}`.  Whatever you prefer, and then using string replacements on those placeholders with the `$row` values inside the loop:

```
$template = "The account ID is %AccountID%.";

...

while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo str_replace('%AccountID%', $row['AccountID'], $template);
}
```

I'd urge you not to rely on `eval()` here because it'd leave you open to dangerous injections when you don't have full control over the input.

Comment: thanks!! i used   eval("echo $str;"); and it worked for me

Comment: Like I said, don't rely on eval.  What if $str contains `""; unlink('index.php')`.  I just made you delete your index.php file.  If you ever reach for eval in a production environment, you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

this is a way:

```
sprintf('%d%d', $row["AccountID"], $row["CurrencyID"]);
```

%d is integer format

Answer (score 0):

You can find and replace the values within the string using this implode/explode method.

```
$str = '$row["AccountID"].$row["CurrencyID"]'; 

//first remove the '.'
$str = implode('', explode('.', $str));

while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
  $row_str = $str;
  foreach($row as $field=>$value){
     $row_str = implode($value, explode('$row["'.$field.'"]', $row_str ));
  }
  echo $row_str;
}
```